# get ids of all jqgrids in page using jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

We have an MVC3 view with multiple jqgrids in it. I now have have two buttons Expand and Collapse. On Expand button click I need to resize all the jqgrids in the page to increase their width by 100px and On Collpase button click I need to resize all the jqgrids in the page to decrease their width by 100px. Is there any easy way to get all jqGrids using jquery instead of giving `$("#grid1", "#grid2", "#grid3")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using css class. Add a new class say jqgridsClass to all div used for jqGrid like :

```
<div id="grid1" class="jqgridsClass">
<div id="grid2" class="jqgridsClass">
<div id="grid3" class="jqgridsClass">
```

now above statement can be reduced to mere

```
$(".jqgridsClass")
```

from

```
$("#grid1", "#grid2", "#grid3")
```

hope  it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I ca'nt find a way to get all jqGrid instances; but you can add each jqGrid instance reference into an array when you define them.

When you nedd by iterating the array you'll have each grid instance and you can do your stuff.

Code:

```
var $grids = $("#grid1, #grid2, #grid3").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"
    }, {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date"
    }, {
        name: 'blank',
        index: 'blank',
        width: 30
    }, {
        name: 'number',
        index: 'number',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"
    }, {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"
    }],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
    // ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}
});

$("#resizeMe").click(function () {
    $($grids).each(function (index) {
        $(this).jqGrid('setGridHeight', "20px");
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/XQmgK/